# How to autosubmit a form in JS when a field reaches a number of characters?

Tags: javascript, php

What better way to make a form having a autosubmit when a field is completely filled? I need him to do it when it reaches 7 characters in the field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
window.onload=function() {
    document.getElementById('myField').oninput=function() {
        if (this.value.length >= 7) {
            document.getElementById('myForm').submit();
        }
    };
};
//]]>
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="myForm" method="post" action="thispage.php">
<input id="myField" name="myField" type="text" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

would probably do the trick. However, what if the user makes a mistake on the 7th character? It seems a bit user-unfriendly to automatically submit the form like this.

Comment: And you should check for copy/paste commands on the field too.

Comment: `<input name="myField" type="text" onchange="if (this.value.length >= 7) this.form.submit()" />`

Answer (score 2):

Try this and check it over jsfiddle link:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").on('keyup',function(){
        var len = parseInt($("#submit").val().length);
        if( len > 5) { 
          $("#form").submit();
        }
    });
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/a7bjowLq/6/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you could do that, by check for length of characters and if your number comes up, then `submit()`.

```js
var field = document.getElementById('text-1');

field.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  console.log('working');
  if (e.target.value.length >= 7) {
    console.log('auto ');
    document.forms[0].submit();
  }
}, true);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Example</title>
</head>

<body>

  <form action="/" id="myForm" mehtod="POST">
    <input type="text" value="" name="text-1" id="text-1" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="sub" id="sub" />
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```